# Install python packages on a remote server without access to root

Tags: python

I want to install some python packages on a remote server where I can actually log in and work on some existing python packages. Sometimes I need new python packages like easydict, then I have to install it. However, since I don't have access to the root (I mean I cannot sudo). How to solve this problem? Is it impossible to debug on someone else's computer where you cannot even "sudo"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for sudo if you want to install packages locally. Generally, you should always use a virtualenv; once that is activated, all packages install within that virtualenv only, with no need for admin privileges.